# WCF Client works with Visual Studio Host but not with custom Host program

Tags: c#, wcf, activex, host

I have a wcf project, very standard in first place.
The problem is when i Host it with Visual Studio, it works just fine
But when i host it with my custom made program, im getting errors.

**System.Exception: Couldn't create ActiveX Component.
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject(String PathName, String Class)**

**System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The type "DiskViewBox.DiskViewItem" in assembly "DiskViewBox, Version=1.0.3401.18107, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" is not marked as serialisable.**

I want to run it as a Windows Service later on.

I assume the problem is not in the client, because it works, and unfortunately i dont know how Visual Studio is hosting it, so i cant compare it to the custom Host.

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using WcfService1;

namespace WcfServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Step 1: Create a URI to serve as the base address.
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/");

            // Step 2: Create a ServiceHost instance.
            using (ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress))
            {

                try
                {
                    // Step 3: Add a service endpoint.
                    selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new NetTcpBinding(), "IService1");

                    // Step 4: Enable metadata exchange.
                    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                    //smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                    selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                    // Step 5: Start the service.
                    selfHost.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");

                    // Close the ServiceHost to stop the service.
                    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate the service.");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    selfHost.Close();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException ce)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
                    selfHost.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Bei der Bereitstellung des Dienstbibliothekprojekts muss der Inhalt der Konfigurationsdatei der 
app.config-Datei des Hosts hinzugefügt werden. System.Configuration unterstützt keine Konfigurationsdateien für Bibliotheken. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The client is written in VB because the access is from a VB environment and its easier to Debug in VS.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim addr As String
        addr = "service:mexAddress=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/Mex"","
        addr = addr + "address=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/"","
        addr = addr + "contract=""IService1"", contractNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"","
        addr = addr + "binding=""NetTcpBinding_IService1"", bindingNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"""

        Dim service1 As Object
        MsgBox(addr)
        Dim path As String
        path = "C:\\tmp\\test1.docm"

        service1 = GetObject(addr)

        MsgBox(service1.GetData(112))

        'Dim result As Variant
        'result = service1.GetString


    End Sub

End Module
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is an .exe file in the bin directory of the project file. When it is opened with administrator authority, the wcf service is successfully hosted in the console application, and then the client calls it.

Comment: I have following folder structure:
WcfService1 - contains the .dll with functions and app.config
WcfServiceHost - contains the Host.exe that is planned to run(1st code mentioned above)
WcfServiceClient - contains the Client.exe (3rd code above)
The problem is: i get an error in the client.exe while hosting with Host.exe, but not getting an error while hosting with Visual Studio Debugger

Comment: You can take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/activex-component-can-t-create-object-or-return-reference-to-this-object-error-4